# Generate Swagger OpenApi Spec 3.0 by using GO framework

Tags: go, swagger

In our project, we currently utilize Swagger 2.0 for API documentation, and the Swagger file generation is automated using the Swaggo library (https://github.com/swaggo/swag). However, it's important to note that Swaggo primarily supports Swagger 2.0, and we are considering migrating our Swagger 2.0 specifications to the newer OpenAPI 3.0 version.

Could someone please assist me in finding a stable Golang library that supports the generation of Swagger 3.0 version files?